# Find minimum absolute sum of 2 numbers from an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

### The problem

Given an unsorted array consists of any integers *(positive, negative, zero)*, find 2 numbers whose sum's absolute value is minimum.

e.g

- `[-60, 40, -100, -7, 1, 3, 110, 0, 7, -4, 90]` -> `|7 + -7| = 0`
- `[-60, 40, -100, -7, 1, 3, 110, 4, 59]` -> `|-60 + 59| = 1`

---

### Current solution

Steps:

- Sort the array first.
- Then loop start from both end, towards the middle, mark left pointer as `pa`, right pointer as `pb`.

  - while(pb>pa)

    - if sum > 0, pb--
    - else if sum < 0, pa++
    - else return 0

Tips:

- The code that calculate & keep track the minimum absolute sum is omitted in above steps.

**Time complexity:** `O(n*lg(n))`, due to the sorting.

---

### The question is

- Is there any `O(n)` solution?

Comment: Have you looked over the third method in [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/), specifically the one about an O(n) and O(1) solution?

Comment: @ladygremlin Seems the problem in that link is kinda irrelevant with this problem

Comment: I figured maybe the traversal algorithm would be helpful, even if the summation problem was different. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you're assuming that the addition is O(1), then you must be assuming that the integers in the array have some fixed upper bound (such as 2³²), which means that you can do a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) in O(*n*) time.

Comment: You can create a C++ `std::unordered_map` in O(n), i.e. an array with a hash function. Then, for each element `x`, you can check if `-x` is inside the map. If no success, do it again looking for `x+1` etc. You will get a solution in O(n x min). However, your solution should be faster in practice, even for low value of the minimum

Comment: @ruakh Nice tip on the `radix sort`, though `radix sort` only applies on non-negative integers I guess, thus maybe need to split the numbers into 2 groups first: negative & non-negative, then sort respectively, then merge. And when sort the negative group might sort their negation instead.

Comment: @EricWang: I'm not sure why you claim that "`radix sort` only applies on non-negative integers". It is not difficult at all to implement it in a way that works just fine for an array that can include negative numbers.

Comment: @ruakh Ok, good to know that, I didn't implemented it yet, just checked the algorithm roughly on Wikipedia.